# Many-to-Many relationship in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, foreign-keys, many-to-many

This is probably a dumb question and not specific to Google App Engine, but here goes:

say I have in my models.py file:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
   author = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Author)

class Author(ndb.Model):
   books = ndb.StructuredProperty(Book, repeated=True)
```

I'm getting `Import Error: cannot import name Author` right now because I define the Author model below the Book Model. As you can see it's like a chicken-and-egg problem. One of the models needs to be defined before the other and will therefore result in an import error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd imagine this may be a common problem?

Comment: I think it may be because you should specify a kind by name (i.e. string) not by actual model class: `author = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Author')`

Comment: Jus a nit pick, but the relationship you describe is not Many to Many, it's either One > Many or Many -> One.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I changed so now I specify kind by string `kind='Author`. But now when I try to query:
`Book.query(Author=author_instance)` I'm getting an error `author_instance is not defined`

Comment: I don't believe specifying name in string is right actually, if you look here at code from Google https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/f39766c90875f3ccbe478d8b0aa53200bf996c40/appengine/standard/ndb/async/guestbook.py#L36 they specify kind name directly

Comment: Probably need to show all of the amended code.

Comment: Thanks. I also have another question: instead of storing the Key, can I just store the ID of the author entity instead? And then simply retrieve the entity via Key('Author', numericID)?

Is one more efficient than the other?